# Question about the default page navigator XBAP or XAML with WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, uinavigationcontroller, xbap

I'm wondering how i can acces to the default navigation bar ?

Is it a controler ?

Is it the Uri.navigate ?

Can I customize it ? Will it show in a browser or the use of it only make sense with Windows app ?

Is it posible to make it visible before any pages are instanciated by my main app ? *before historical navigation is created ?

**ScreenShot**

[Application Window Showing NavBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0gi6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think your searching for the NavigationUIVisibility property?
You can use the NavigationService to access the navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks I'll check that :)